# Let $g: C\to D$ be a one-to-one function, $A \subseteq C$, $B \subseteq C$. Prove that if $A\cap B = \emptyset$, then $g[A] \cap g[B] = \emptyset$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $g: C\to D$ be a one-to-one function, $A \subseteq C$, $B \subseteq C$. Prove that if $A\cap  B = \emptyset$, then $g[A] \cap g[B] = \emptyset$.

There is a lot of information here and the properties of the image of a set confuses me. I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: What have you tried? Why don't you assume the intersection of the images is not empty, and then look at the inverse image?

Comment: Take set A, collect all the images g(x) such that $x$ is an element of  A. you have built the set g[A]. So g[A] is the set of all $y$ belonging to D that have a preimage in set A.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Use contrapositive: if $g(A)\cap g(B)\neq \varnothing$, $g$ is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

- In order to prove the conditional statement, you have to show that, if the antecedent is true, then the consequent cannot be false ( under the special hypothesis of your problem).
- Assume A and B are disjoint ( this is the antecedent).
- Suppose that some object $y$ belongs both to g[A] and g[B] ( in other words, suppose g[A] and g[B] are not disjoint). ( This is the negation of the consequent).
- In that case, $y$ has a preimage in $A$ and also a preimage in $B$ . That is, there is some $x_1$ in $A$ mapped to $y$ and also some $x_2$ in $B$ mapped to $y$.
- But we have asssumed that A and B are disjoint.
- What do you conclude from this as to the question of knowing whether $x_1$ and $x_2$ are identical or not?
- In case you are forced to conclude they are not identical, are you consistent with your hypothesis?
- Remember that a function is 1-1 just in case non-identical preimages have non-identical images under this function.